# RxJs subscriptions in services... Memory leak?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm talking with another developer about some memory leaks in an app I'm working on. I'm being told that I should close subscriptions in services used by my components whenever the component is destroyed but that doesn't really make sense to me. The services are all providedIn root; they're shared among other components. Some are imported by components that are never destroyed (like a route monitoring sub).

I'm mainly looking for a sanity check here. Do (and HOW do) subscriptions in services that are providedIn root cause memory leaks, if they're only instantiated once and shared among other components? Feels like I'd need to re-subscribe my services' subs every time I import the service, but that feels like an anti-pattern to the way services work, especially services that are single-instance.

Asked another way, when a service that's providedIn root is imported to another component, are subscriptions in the service re-used? When a component that imports a service that's providedIn root is destroyed, if it's the only ingester of that service, is the service also destroyed, or does it stick around for when it's needed next?

Comment: you have memory leaks but also, do you really want the subscription code to run outside the lifecycle of the component? e.g. if the network hangs a long time. If you use component variables typescript won't tell you these have been garbage collected

Answer (score 1):

You do have a memory leak because you'll create subscriptions that will never end even when your component is destroyed : this is why `takeUntilDestroyed` has been added in v16.

Subscriptions are never "reused". The observable might HOT and producing but the subscription is the call to `subscribe()`. Each time you call it you have to think about how this subscription will end :

- `takeUntil`/`takeWhile`/`takeUntilDestroyed`
- `Subscription.unsubscribe()`
- the emitter completing (for example a simple HTTP call will complete after the response is passed to the observable).

Also service are only destroyed when there injector is destroyed. The root injector is only destroyed when you destroy the whole app :

```
const appRef: ApplicationRef = await bootstrapApplication(RootComponent);
appRef.destroy() // Destroying the app
```

Comment: But future components will re-use the same subscriptions, yes?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: "Each time you call it you have to think about how this subscription will end" Yes, I get that. What I'm saying is that the service should happily hum along using the same subscriptions it made when it was instantiated, yes? It won't create duplicates of the subscription in the same way a component would if it were destroyed without unsubbing.

Comment: Are sure you understand what `subscription` means ?  A subscription is return on `subscribe()`. There is no reuse when calling a method .

Comment: Yes, I know what a subscription is. What I'm trying to determine is whether subscriptions in services get duplicated when different components import the service. I think it's perfectly fine to refer to that as "reuse" because the same subscription is being used, by proxy, by multiple components and multiple instances of the same component. Getting hung up on minutiae isn't really helpful.

Comment: "subscriptions IN services" - the service internally calls subscribe as part of its lifecycle and unsubscribes when the service is destroyed - OK.  "subscriptions TO services" - the component subscribes to something in the service.  The component NEEDS to unsubscribe when the component is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: I would argue that a subscription that is never destroyed is not necessarily the same thing as a memory leak. There can be cases where it makes sense to never unsubscribe from a subscription because it is always needed.

### Memory Leak Question

> I'm mainly looking for a sanity check here. Do (and HOW do)
> subscriptions in services that are providedIn root cause memory leaks,
> if they're only instantiated once and shared among other components?

I want to focus in on a specific part of your question here.

> if they're only instantiated once and shared among other components

Assuming by "they're" you mean the service itself (because its provided in root), you do not necessarily have a memory leak. At least based on [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) of a memory leak (emphasis mine):

> "a memory leak is a type of resource leak that occurs when a computer
> program incorrectly manages memory allocations in a way that memory
> ***which is no longer needed*** is not released".

I'll make the case that a subscription that is never destroyed is not necessarily the same thing as a memory leak. Sometimes it makes sense to never unsubscribe from a subscription because it is always needed.

I've seen this a lot in larger applications, where there is a service that is provided in root, that subscribes to something in its constructor.

I'm imagining what you are talking about is something like below (but feel free to add some code to your post to clarify).

#### code snippet 1

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class StatService {
  constructor(private cs: CharacterService, private es: EquipService) {
    // combineLatest so that whenever character or equips change, recompute stats
    combineLatest([this.cs.character$, this.es.loadout$])
    .subscribe(([c, loadout]) => {
      if(c && loadout) {
        this.computeEverything(c, this.es.getStatsFromEquips())
      }
    })
  }
...
}
```

Again referring to the above definition of a memory leak, I would argue this is fine because:

1. this subscription is created only once.
2. this subscription will never be "no longer needed".

It is totally possible to create a memory leak with services that are provided in root, generally with code outside of the service constructor. Modifying the above example slightly (moving the subscription into a public "init" function).

#### code snippet 2 (bad example)

```
// bad example
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class StatService {
  constructor(private cs: CharacterService, private es: EquipService) { }

  public init() {
    // combineLatest so that whenever character or equips change, recompute stats
    combineLatest([this.cs.character$, this.es.loadout$])
    .subscribe(([c, loadout]) => {
      if(c && loadout) {
        this.computeEverything(c, this.es.getStatsFromEquips())
      }
    })
  }
...
}
```

The risk here is now it is possible for the init function to be called multiple times by other services/components, thus creating multiple subscriptions, and you would have no way of unsubscribing from them (this would be a memory leak).

A simple (maybe not the best) fix to the bad example above would just be to keep a reference to the Subscription that is returned from .subscribe(), and unsubscribe from it to prevent multiple subscriptions that you would otherwise have no way of unsubscribing from:

#### code snippet 3

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class StatService {
  private sub: Subscription;
  constructor(private cs: CharacterService, private es: EquipService) { }

  public init() {
    this.sub?.unsubscribe();
    // combineLatest so that whenever character or equips change, recompute stats
    this.sub = combineLatest([this.cs.character$, this.es.loadout$])
    .subscribe(([c, loadout]) => {
      if(c && loadout) {
        this.computeEverything(c, this.es.getStatsFromEquips())
      }
    })
  }
...
}
```

### What about injecting the service in multiple services/components?

> Asked another way, when a service that's providedIn root is imported to another component, are subscriptions in the service re-used?

I don't it's correct to say "re-used" here. Referring to code snippet 1, it is more correct to say "when a service that's providedIn root is injected in another component/service, the subscriptions (that were created in the constructor) in the service are not re-created".

This is because the constructor code of a service providedIn root only runs one time, because the service itself is only created one time (singleton pattern).

### What about when components that inject the service are destroyed?

> When a component that imports a service that's providedIn root is destroyed, if it's the only ingester of that service, is the service also destroyed, or does it stick around for when it's needed next?

Services that are providedIn root are never destroyed. Well, at least not until the entire app is destroyed.

Comment: "I would argue that a subscription that is never destroyed is not necessarily the same thing as a memory leak." That was my thought. My app, though, continues to grow its JS heap size as I work, until it gets large enough that it crashes the browser. Trying to figure out the cause of the leak, and I'm narrowing down things like subscriptions in services.

Comment: yeah I would definitely be checking all of the subscriptions. any that your components create themselves, and any services that are NOT provided in root (at the component level), are the most likely suspects

Comment: Unfortunately., I've checked all my subs. I use an auto-unsubscriber and I also tried manually unsubbing from everything and it's still leaking. Have had 3 fiverr devs look at it so far and nobody can figure it out yet. :| \

Comment: are you able to share the github repo link?

Comment: Nope. It's a private repo for now. :) it's also pretty complex; I wouldn't want to curse you with trying to interpret the data chain. Heh